# Simplifying my code with methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a novice in Ruby and I'm creating little budget helpers.

I know there's a way to simplify this code further, and I can't seem to wrap my head around what method I would need to create. I'm repeating `needs`, `wants`, `save` and fifty, thirty, twenty, etc.:

```
puts "What's your annual income?"
annual_income = gets.to_i

weeks = 52.1775
monthly_income = ((annual_income / weeks) * 2)
weekly_income = (annual_income / weeks) 
needs = 0.5
wants = 0.3
save = 0.2

def calc_amount(income, expense)
  sprintf('%.2f',(income * expense))
end

# Monthly 
fifty_percent_monthly = calc_amount(monthly_income, needs)
puts "You should spend no more than $#{fifty_percent_monthly} on 'Needs' a month."

thirty_percent_monthly = calc_amount(monthly_income, wants)
puts "You should spend no more than $#{thirty_percent_monthly} on 'Wants' a month."

twenty_percent_monthly = calc_amount(monthly_income, save)
puts "You should save $#{twenty_percent_monthly} a month."

# Each paycheck
fifty_percent_weekly = calc_amount(weekly_income, needs)
puts "You should spend no more than $#{fifty_percent_weekly} on 'Needs' each paycheck."

thirty_percent_weekly = calc_amount(weekly_income, wants)
puts "You should spend no more than $#{thirty_percent_weekly} on 'Wants' each paycheck."

twenty_percent_weekly = calc_amount(weekly_income, save)
puts "You should save $#{twenty_percent_weekly} each paycheck."

# Total spent each year
yearly_needs = calc_amount(annual_income, needs)
puts "You'll be spending $#{yearly_needs} on 'Needs' each year."

yearly_wants = calc_amount(annual_income, wants)
puts "You'll be spending $#{yearly_wants} on 'Wants' each year."

yearly_savings = calc_amount(annual_income, save
puts "Congrats! Your total savings each year will be $#{yearly_savings}"
```

Comment: A better place for this question is probably [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Alrighty! Thank you. I'll be sure to post there next time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to loop over every type of time period and then loop over every item in your budget within that.  Here is a simple way you could accomplish it:

```
puts "What's your annual income?"
annual_income = gets.to_i

budget = {
  :needs => 0.5,
  :wants => 0.3,
  :save => 0.2,
}

periods = {
  'weekly' => 52.1775,
  'monthly' => 12,
  'yearly' => 1,
}

periods.each do |period_name, periods_per_year|
  budget.each do |line_item_name, line_item_fraction|
    amount = annual_income.to_f/periods_per_year * line_item_fraction
    puts "You should spend %0.2f on '%s' %s" % [amount, line_item_name, period_name]
  end
end
```

The output is not exactly the same as yours, but it works.  Here is what I get if I enter 1000:

```
You should spend 9.58 on 'needs' weekly
You should spend 5.75 on 'wants' weekly
You should spend 3.83 on 'save' weekly
You should spend 41.67 on 'needs' monthly
You should spend 25.00 on 'wants' monthly
You should spend 16.67 on 'save' monthly
You should spend 500.00 on 'needs' yearly
You should spend 300.00 on 'wants' yearly
You should spend 200.00 on 'save' yearly
```

Comment: Perfect! That's enough to get me use to the idea of how it would work.

Comment: +1, nicely done. Besides the excellent refactoring, using String's `%` instead of the traditional `sprintf` is idiomatic Ruby. The only thing I see you missed was the use of a dollar sign in front of the values, but that could have been assigned to a constant, and then substituted into the format string, allowing the code to work for any currency with a minor tweak.